# how to use clearfix to seperate two navbar and container in bootstrap 3.0

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for a while ago and i get stuck how to separate navbar and div having container class having full width. Actually navbar hides the div having container class. My code:-

```
<nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-fluid navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand">Toggle Navigation</a>

        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <h1>HELLO WORLD!</h1>
    </div>
```

I also tried to put navbar and container in different div having float element left but no luck it still overlap it.
Please help.

Comment: Could you please post a Fiddle?

Comment: here is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jasonrana/pggry5m2/

Comment: Better use a stack snippet than a fiddle these days :)

Comment: clear fix will not work because `nav` is using `position:fixed` because of `.navbar-fixed-top` class, you can use `.navbar-static-top` for nav instead of `.navbar-fixed-top` class which has `position:relative`

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/pggry5m2/1/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes I appreciate your help but what if i want navbar to be fixed on top rather than to be static ?

Comment: so you can give `padding-top` to the `.container`

Comment: yeah thats true.. but for responsive we need to set different padding-top for different devices.